# list.forEach doesn't await properly in async method

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

When using `await` in a `forEach`, the code doesn't await, and keeps executing the code after the `forEach`, but, when using a normal `for`, it awaits properly, se the following snippet:

```
Future<void> uploadTexts(List<String> someTexts) async {
    for(int i = 0; i < someTexts.length ; i++) {
      var text = someTexts[i];
      if (text  != null) {
        await uploadText(text);
      }
    }
    print("THIS PRINTS AFTER THE FOR IS DONE");
  }
```

```
Future<void> uploadTexts(List<String> someTexts) async {

 someTexts.where((text) => text != null).forEach((text) async{
    await uploadText(text);
  });
  print("THIS PRINTS BEFORE THE FOREACH IS DONE");
}
```

The first sample will print after the for is finished, while the second example will print before the for is finished.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `for` you perform some action n times in your code, so every `await` works as expected. With `forEach` you start some operation to every element of list and continue to do following code, so in this case you don't wait for result of `await`

**UPD:**

Here is solution for `forEach`:

```
Future<void> uploadTexts(List<String> someTexts) async {
  List<String> filtered = someTexts.where((text) => text != null);
  await Future.forEach(filtered, (text) async {
    await uploadText(text);
  });
  print("THIS PRINTS BEFORE THE FOREACH IS DONE");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to await for the `foreach`?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The only way I've found is `Future.forEach`